# How to set CampaignId as external Id?

Tags: soql, externalid

I have trigger that contains query below:

```
List<CampaignMember> campaignMembers = [SELECT Id, CampaignId, Campaign_Name__c FROM CampaignMember WHERE CampaignId IN: setCampaignIds];
```

I already filtered out and the query is not in the loop but it gave me this error

```
Opportunity_Trigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type (more than 100000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing.
```

I contacted SFDC Support and they suggest me to use external id.But when I open CampaignMember object,I cannot see CampaignId field.Is this mean this field is not configurable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CampaignId is automatically indexed, as are all lookup fields. The problem is that your campaigns are too big. You'd have to be more selective, such as limiting the query to simply 50,000 rows (which is the most you can query anyways). You'll need to convert your code to asynchronous (read: batchable) code in order to process campaigns of this size.

Comment: I see some code with limit 1000 ,50000 and wonder are they just simply put to avoid exception ?Is there any data can be missed out during the query?

Comment: @unidha Data *will* most likely be missed, so you will need to come up with an alternative way to process more than 50,000 rows of data-- and this will mean that you need to go with asynchronous code. Processing tons of data in a single trigger is a bad idea anyways, as every time a user tries to save data, they'd wait a long time. This is one of the reasons why these limits are in place, to keep the system responsive enough for people to use.

Comment: Yes,I agree that we should use batch if the data more than 50 k,but when I check the log file;it bumped into exception while it only process one row of data.Is IN in the query causing exception SELECT Id, CampaignId, Campaign_Name__c FROM CampaignMember WHERE CampaignId IN: setCampaignIds ?